# Linux and Physical and Virtual CPUs

Tags: linux, unix

How to find out how many cpu's a linux machine is using (for an application and for the whole system) and if they are physical or virtual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Will tell you how many CPUs were detected by the kernel.  I am unsure exactly what you mean by "physical" as compared to "virtual" CPUs -- unless the OS is being run in a virtualized/emulated environment, the CPUs listed there will all be physical.

As for which CPUs an application is using, it will by default use any and all available CPUs.  Even if there is only one thread in the process, this thread may still switch between CPUs when the kernel deems it necessary.

You can use the `taskset` command to set the CPU affinity of a process, which will limit which CPUs it is allowed to run on.  To fetch the CPU affinity of a process, run

```
taskset -p $PID_OF_PROCESS
```

Answer (score 1):

`cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 0):

for linux you type:
dmesg |grep DMI

### VIRTUAL HOST OUTPUT

[root@myhost ~]# dmesg |grep DMI
DMI 2.3 present.
DMI: Microsoft Corporation Virtual Machine/Virtual Machine, BIOS 090006  05/23/2012

[root@myhost ~]# dmesg |grep -i virtual
DMI: Microsoft Corporation Virtual Machine/Virtual Machine, BIOS 090006  05/23/2012
Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input1
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
input: Microsoft Vmbus HID-compliant Mouse as /devices/virtual/input/input4

### FOR PHYSICAL HOST EXAMPLE

[root@backdev1 ~]# dmesg |grep DMI
DMI 2.5 present.
DMI: IBM System x3650 M3 -[7945AC1]-/90Y4784, BIOS -[D6E153AUS-1.12]- 06/30/2011

Comment: Do your examples only have one CPU each? Or how do you use this to tell how many CPUs there are?